# Python. Recurring error in int condition

Tags: python-3.x

**Q:** Aleksa is having a New Year's Eve party! His house has a magic doorway that only allows  person to enter per  second, and he knows  people will show up.

If two guests arrive at same time, one guest must wait for the other to enter. If two guests arrive at different times, the guest arriving first must enter first.

Given the arrival times for all  guests, determine the entry time of the last guest.

**Input Format**

The first line contains an integer, , denoting the number of guests. 
The second line contains  integers, , where  is the arrival time of  guest.

**Constraints**

**Output Format**

Print the time that the last guest enters the magic doorway.

```
Sample Input 1:

8
2 2 2 2 4 4 4 6 

Sample Output 1:
9

Sample Input 2:
3
2000 2015 2015

Sample Output 2:
2016
```

HERE IS MY CODE> PLEASE TELL ME THE ERROR AND RATE MY LOGIC

```
N=int(input())
pop=list(map(int,input().split()))
na=[]
kar=[]
count=0
for x in range(6666666666666):
    if pop!=list():
        ol=min(pop)
    for item in pop:
        if item==ol:
            na.append(item)
            pop.remove(item)
        else:
            pass
    kol=len(na)
    na=[]
    if kar==list():
        count=ol+(kol-1)
        kar.append(count)
    elif kar!=list() and kar[-1]>ol:
        top=kar[-1]+kol
        kar.append(top)
    elif kar!=list() and kar[-1]<ol:
        pop=ol+kol-1
        kar.append(pop)
elif pop==list():
    print(kar[-1])
    break
```

I am getting an error like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 8, in <module>
    ol=min(pop)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Any suggestions and please tell me if my logic is correct and good enough? I am a beginner who started python three weeks back.

Comment: Post all code here formatted without the numbers in front of each line so it's readable. Also, post the full error with trace.

Comment: @MohammedIfreen You make `pop` a number here: `pop=ol+kol-1`, but `min` expects that `pop` is a list. I'm not sure what your intent is there.

Comment: yournibtebt: Bro what you meant here?

Comment: What I meant is if the final element in list kar is less than the next waiting guest... then just add the guest number + the number of times the same number repeats.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for rating your logic. This is not an answer to your exception (see comments for that), but to your solution:

First step in programming is to think what to do:

- The first number of guests is irrelevant, you get that from splitting the times
- the times are important
- no guest can arrive earlier the 0
- for each guest her time is either the time she arrives or later, if earlier ones are still waiting
- the first one gets in at her time, the next either 1 later (if arrived at same time) or when she arrives 
  ==> you need to track when the last guest got in

---

```
_ = input()       # dont care
timeData = list(map(int,input().split()))

lastGuest = -1          # time the lastGuest entered, init to before anybody arrived
for time in timeData:
    if time > lastGuest:    # arrival later then lastGuest, so thats the new lastGuest time
        lastGuest = time
    elif time <= lastGuest: # arrival earlier or at same time then lastGuest: we enter at +1
        lastGuest += 1

print(lastGuest)
```

Done.

Comment: Thanks. I think I made it way too complex. My logic is bad. :(

Comment: @NeverGiveUp too complex, yep. Modelling problems is 75% of coding - you'll get there eventually.

Comment: Agreed Sir. Hopefully. Thanks for answering.